# Asking questions involving the comparision of and/or design decisions behind programming languages

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I did not see the following covered in the faq. Hence, I felt the need to ask here.

I want to ask a question in Programmers about the thought that was involved in a particular, somewhat recent, programming language. The question is not to start a flame war, but to ask people who might use the language to comment.

Is that Okay for Programmers, or should I go to that language's Google groups?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't sound appropriate for Programmers since it seems like you're trying to have a discussion. Stack Exchange sites are designed to address practical, answerable questions and not to have an extended discussion on a topic.

Comment: I agree but I would like to point out that you will only start a discussion if you ask about what the members of the site think of those design decisions. On the other hand, if you ask about what the documented motivations of the designers were, you are asking about a fact, and any serious answer will avoid discussion (instead, it will report opinions expressed by the designers and references to documents in which these opinions were expressed).

Comment: @Giorgio That depends on the such documents or statements existing. Also, specifically asking what people think may be too localized (if there aren't citable resources available) or not a real question (if you're requesting resources only - resource request questions are not a good fit, per previous discussions on Meta).